# how to loop each row from one column and search if that string exists in other column in second excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

please help me with this, appreciate your help. I wrote something like this but looks like it is not working. Please let me know your inputs.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('Manual reports.xlsx')
df3 = pd.read_csv('Audit.csv')
df4 = df3['File'].str.split(';').str[1]
for name1 in df1['Destination Path'].str.split('m').str[1]:
  if name1 in df4:
     print(name1,"yes" )
else:
     print(name1, "no")
 ` ` `
```

Comment: It'd be better if you add some sample data to your question. You can do `df[:5].to_dict()` and add the output data to the question for both the excel and csv files

Comment: What is your desired result please? I see this having a combination of results. Share the sample source data and sample output file. We should be able to help you.